# Why does 'scientific' change the meaning of 'precision'?

Tags: c++11

Here's a MWE:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout.precision(17);
    std::cout << 1.2345678901234567890 << '\n';
    std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::scientific);
    std::cout.precision(17);
    std::cout << 1.2345678901234567890 << '\n';
}
```

On my machine this prints:

```
1.2345678901234567
1.23456789012345669e+00
```

The last output has an additional digit (`18` instead of the `17` I explicitly requested). Why?

Comment: No idea why this was dowvnoted, this is an interesting question. Cppreference explicitely says that hexadecimal floats ignore the precision specifier, but says no such things about `scientific`.

Comment: I'd be interested to see the outputs for different precision settings...say 3, 10, 20...

Comment: @Grantly here you go.

Comment: You might also find that scientific form keeps 1 maybe 2 trailing zeros as part of the precision formatting (if you modify your test value, this is worth testing too)  UNLESS the trailing zeros have a non zero trailing value... 1.2001  should not output 1.200 (3 precision), but 1.20000 should output as 1.200 (3 prec)

Comment: note  that this number is not representable by double type (IEEE754). Instead 1.23456789012345669043213547411E0 is used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It [follows the rules of `printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put/put), after having assembled a format specifier from the stream state.

```
int main()
{
    std::printf("%.17g\n", 1.2345678901234567890);
    std::printf("%.17f\n", 1.2345678901234567890);
    std::printf("%.17e\n", 1.2345678901234567890);

    std::printf("%.17g\n", 1234567890.1234567890);
    std::printf("%.17f\n", 1234567890.1234567890);
    std::printf("%.17e\n", 1234567890.1234567890);
}
```

With neither `std::ios_base::scientific` nor `std::ios_base::fixed`, the format is `"%.17g"`, which corresponds to *17 total digits*

With `std::ios_base::scientific` the format is `"%.17e"`, which corresponds to 17 digits after the decimal, plus the exponent. As there is only ever one digit before the decimal, this leads to *18 total digits*

With `std::ios_base::fixed` the format is `"%.17f"`, which corresonds to 17 digits after the decimal. There may be multiple digits before the decimal, this leads to *18 or more total digits*

Comment: I think that's the correct answer (which is baiscally keeping compatibility to C). Could you please link to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put/put? In "Stage 1: ... If the type `vs` is a floating-point type, ..." this is documented.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* this is because of how the digits are counted. Consider an altered example:

```
std::cout.precision(4);
std::cout << 12.345678901234567890 << '\n';
std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::scientific);
std::cout.precision(4);
std::cout << 12.345678901234567890 << '\n';
```

In this case, the output is:

```
12.35
1.2346e+01
```

As you can clearly observe, `precision` means "total number of digits" in regular float form, and "number of decimal digits" when the scientific notation is used (because it implies that there's always one digit in front of the decimal point).

Comment: Yeah I agree, from what I remember from Physics... Even if the first digit before the decimal point is a zero - like 0.123 - then scientific notation always shifts so that 1 non zero digit is used. (1.23 x 10^-1 for example).  Although the trailing zeros are somewhat significant too